# How to extend mysqli class into other class methods

Tags: php, mysqli

Hey sorry for the stupid question. I have read lots about oop in php so i decided to try. i have a blog running procedural php and all works fine but i have mysql not mysqli on the code and i decided to upgrade to the new mysqli. the problem here is really query the database to get results. i have been on the problem for two days now. here's a code example of what i want to implement.

```
class myDB extends mysqli
{
  //perform mysqli connection to host here and return  $connection_handle
}

class siteConfig
{
   private function getConfig($id)
  {
   $res = $connection_handle->query("SELECT * from config where id='1'");
   $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
   return $row['option'];
  }

}
```

on the main index file i would do this

```
$c = new siteConfig();
echo $c->getConfig(1);
//and this will return the result of the query.
```

also please pardon my programming logic and still a very terrible newbie to the oop world

any ideas will be helpful thank you.

PS

this is  working example of the code am using

```
$db_link = mysqli_connect(DB,HOST,DB_USER,DB,PASS,DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());

class myDB extends mysqli
{
  public function getConfig($id, $db_link) // thanks cbuckley
{
 $db_link = $this->db_link;
     $res = mysqli_query($this->db_link,"SELECT * from config where id='1'");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
     return $row['option'];
}    
}
```

i have defined the constants already and the connection is successful but the select is not working. on the index page this goes [code] include('inc/dbc.php');

```
 $db = new MyDB();
 echo $db->getConfig(1, $db_link);
```

please let me know where am missing it or if possible refactor the code for me where neccessary

Comment: Could you please explain what is the purpose of Extending the mysqli class (specialization? encapsulation of business logic)?

Comment: Otherwise, you have an error in your code : if the "getConfig" function is private, you cannot invoke it from outside the class "$c->getConfig" would trigger an error

Comment: pardon folks...like i said an still a newbie to oop...what do you suggest? @ibatarek

Comment: Read about [visibility](http://php.net/oop5.visibility); only public methods/properties are accessible outside the class. Otherwise, your example is good.

Comment: Using `mysqli_connect()` is the procedural style, not the OOP style. `$db_link = new mysqli()` is the OOP equivalent. Have a look at the [basic examples](http://php.net/mysqli.construct). If you want to use OOP, basically avoid using any of the `mysqli_*` functions :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just extend the mysqli class and add your functions to myDB?

```
class myDB extends mysqli
{
   public function getConfig($id) // thanks cbuckley
  {
   $res = $this->query("SELECT * from config where id='1'");
   $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
   return $row['option'];
  }    
}

$db = new myDB;
$db->getConfig($id);
```

You can call any mysqli function inside myDb by using the $this keyword (which refers to itself and since "it self" extends mysqli, it will have all the functions mysqli has + the ones you add)

Comment: how about when i want to make other queries to the database? do i add all of them as methods to the mydb class?...do you have any idea i could write a generic query code and the blog will have plenty database queries...thank for the answer though

Comment: you can always call $db->query(); in the above example since all mysqli functions are still part of you class. but you will probably want to create query wrappers for insert update and delete inside your myDB class. Also consider using a framework that includes Models.. like Yii or Zend (amongst many others. ;)

Comment: i have yii and zend installed on my localmachine but they are not newbie friendly at all

Comment: This couples business logic (getting site config) with library code (database adapter). The OP's example is probably better in that it separates these concerns. And the method is still private :-)

Comment: am really lost in the....in the code above do i add the db connection code or jus go straight to the code and execute it?

Answer (score 2):

It's good to keep the separation between your database connection and any business logic, so your example is good. There are just a couple of extra things that need sorting out, namely how the application logic has access to the database handler. Here's an example:

```
class MyDB extends mysqli {
    // any custom DB stuff here
}

class SiteConfig {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(MyDB $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getConfig($id) {
        $statement = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM config WHERE id = ?');
        $statement->bind_param('i', $id);

        if ($statement->execute()) {
            $row = $statement->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            return $row['option'];
        }
    }
}

$db = new MyDB('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');
$config = new SiteConfig($db);
var_dump($config->getConfig(1));
```

A couple of points of interest here:

- **[Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)**: passing `$db` into your config class
- **[Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)**: the SiteConfig class is not responsible for setting up the database connection, thus keeping its role clean and well-defined
- **[Method and property visibility](http://php.net/oop5.visibility)**: `$config->db` is 
  declared protected, so it can't be accessed outside of the scope of the class
- **[Type hinting](http://php.net/language.oop5.typehinting)**: forcing the first parameter of SiteConfig's constructor to be an instance of MyDB
- **[Class properties](http://php.net/language.oop5.properties)**: setting the `$db` instance as a property of the SiteConfig class, so it can be used in `getConfig()`
- **[Method and property visibility](http://php.net/oop5.visibility)**: `$config->db` is 
  declared protected, so it can't be accessed outside of the scope of the class
- **[Prepared statements](http://php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements)**: more efficient queries that get protection against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for free

Comment: thank you soooo much cbuckley....how ever, this is very advanced for a noob like me pls break down...an just starting out with mysqli and am very limited in its understanding pls expanciate on custom db stuff and what the myDB class returns....Thank again

Comment: MyDB is just a child of mysqli, so you'd use it like the [normal examples](http://php.net/mysqli.construct#refsect1-mysqli.construct-examples). In my code, MyDB adds no real value, but it'd be the right place to put things like database connection error handling etc. I've added the connection parameters to make it clearer. Then all you're doing is passing the connection in to the SiteConfig [constructor](http://php.net/__construct). I've also added a couple more points of interest :-)